# VS 2019 Unity namespace doen not work (c#)

Tags: c#, syntax-error, visual-studio-2019

My Visual Studio 2019 doesn't highlight Unity keywords like `Vector3` and classes from other scripts. Although Unity Engine was installed with VS installer and `using UnityEngine;` is put on the top.

It also doesn't show errors in real time in such code like: `string s = 6;`.

Comment: Did you manage to restart VS?

Comment: @Roman Ryzhiy yes, but it didn't work

Comment: oh wait I just found out that there was a 'fix' option in the installer so let's wait a second

Comment: Are you opening Visual Studio directly from Unity3D? (if maybe you opened a file "alone", with a new ad-hoc project instead of using the Unity project, the reference to the lib will be missing)

Comment: @Pac0 yes, and it doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I know, this kind of issue can arise if you have some global syntax issue. For instance, if there is a missnig curly brace `{` or `}` somewhere, or you are trying to write code in the `namespace FooApp { }` block instead of in the `class FooClass {}` block. If you simply create a new basic C# console app, do you have any issue when adding `string s =  6;` as a class field or as a function's code ?

Comment: @Pac0 I ended up downloading VS 2017 and everything worked fine without changing the code, so it's a matter of version I think

Comment: @dzbanecznix Thanks for feedback. I'm sure VS 2019 should be usable somehow. Anyway, you can post your own solution as an answer to your question, it might help other people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install "Visual Studio Tools for Unity" from the Visual Studio Installer.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Installer]